# Trying to get a multiple of 3 and 5 in R

Tags: r

I need a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for numbers that are multiples of three print Multipleof3 instead of the number and for the multiples of five print Multipleof5

```
p2<-function(x){
  x=c(1:100)
  if (x%%3==0){
  print ("Multipleof3")
  } else if (x%%5 == 0){
  print("Multipleof5")
  } else {
   print(x)
  }
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: what is it's a multiple of both? FizzBuzz?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595785/why-isnt-my-fizz-buzz-test-in-r-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
p2<-function(x){
    if (x%%3==0){
        return ("Multipleof3")
    } else if (x%%5 == 0){
        return("Multipleof5")
    } else {
        return(x)
    }
}

p<-Vectorize(p2)

p(1:100)

# [1] "1"           "2"           "Multipleof3" "4"           "Multipleof5" "Multipleof3" "7"           "8"
```

Note : you can replace `p2` by :

```
p2<-function(x){
    return(ifelse(x%%3==0, "Multipleof3", ifelse(x%%5==0, "Multipleof5", x)))
}
```

Your function parameter should not be in the question but defined like this : `function(x)` and when you call the function you put your parameter (`1:100`) at the place of `x`. The `Vectorize` allow to create a new function : `p` which is the same as `p2` but which is capable of handling vectors.

Use :

```
p2<-function(x){
    return(ifelse(x%%3==0 & x%%5==0, "MultipleOfBoth", ifelse(x%%3==0, "Multipleof3", ifelse(x%%5==0, "Multipleof5", x))))
}
```

for handling multiple of 3 and 5.

Comment: Thank you all!!! That's so helpful! :)